# COMPILATION debug=false is killing my ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have a large (to me) ASP.NET (4.5 Framework) application that was working fine when developed in and published from VS2012.

I've since upgraded from VS2012 to VS2013 and I opened the solution without issue and it runs fine locally (on IIS Express).

I don't know if this is a red-herring, but I used NuGet to update the AJAX Control Toolkit for the first time (and its dependencies) and it appears to have worked.

When I publish (file system publish) the site to our web server (IIS 8 in Windows Server 2012) it loads fine UNTIL I change `<compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">` to `debug="false"`.
When I do, the site runs like a pig, sometimes pages don't even load, and its IIS Worker Process spikes the CPU and holds, growing in % until it consumes essentially all the CPU.

EDIT: this happens on the server and on my PC (IIS Express)

This test site's AppPool is running with the identical settings as our live site's AppPool. Of note:

- Enable 32-bit applications: True
- .NET Framework Version: v4.0
- Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated

I expect you'll need more information, but I honestly don't know where to begin and I don't want to overwhelm with unnecessary detail.
Thank you in advance

EDIT: I REALLY should have mentioned this:
the site is precompiled during publish in Release mode. I've never had to change to debug=false in my development environment prior to publish in the past.

I get this for each of the Projects in my solution:
`(0,0): warning : The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly during runtime causing a failure: [projectname], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. The dependencies are: Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. You should either ensure that the dependent assembly is correct for the target framework, or ensure that the target framework you are addressing is that of the dependent assembly.`

**EDIT:** it appears this solution I inherited is a web SITE not APP. I don't know if that comes into play.

Comment: I don't believe the change you describe would cause the symptoms you describe. If you've changed your web.config and hit refresh, yes, you may get a delay for a bit as the site/app pool combo may be rebuilding/recycling but not quite to the extent you describe. 
One question would be why you're deploying at all in debug mode and then turning it off afterwards, but that's one for another day!

Comment: Anything get wrote to event log on the web server?

Comment: try precompiling-- and set your project to release mode with the web.config's debug mode='false' and it should work fine.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: the change I describe caused the symptoms I described. the cpu maxes out and stays that way for hours until I finally stop the appPool.

Comment: @ps2goat: I updated my post to address your good points.

Comment: It appears you're having performance problems. Have you profiled the application?

Comment: @p.campbell, I have not considered WebDeploy. I assumed it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Kyle, it appears I've got many warnings to review in the EventLog; shameful that I didn't look there already.

Comment: Thats a good starting point. Have you got .net framework 4.5 installed on the server already? Are you targetting the full .net 4.5 framework under all the project properties in vs? Or just the "light weight" client?

Comment: @Kyle Are you talking about Portable Class Libraries? The Client Profile doesn't exist in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track now, only other thing it could possibly be, aside from a configuration issue is some conditional code which looks at the 'debug' flag and isn't run when it's set to true.

Comment: @Kyle Target Framework for all projects in the solution is ".NET Framework 4.5". Yes, the server is running my "live" site without issue (debug=false) using the same framework. This all started after my upgrade to VS2013

Comment: @dougajmcdonald No conditional code in my source. :(
Thanks, though.

Comment: VS2013 uses .NET 4.5.1, which is an updated version of 4.5; have you installed that update on your server? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773

Comment: @RichardDeeming: I've confirmed my site's projects are all using Target Framework = ".NET Framework 4.5", not 4.5.1. Also, as I indicated in my question, COMPILATION targetframework="4.5" is also in my web.config.
No, 4.5.1 is not installed on my server, though. I have a short maintenance window this weekend where I'm already scheduled to apply all Windows Updates and this additional piece.

Comment: Make sure the application pool is properly configured and isn't shared with other website on different version of .net

Comment: @the_lotus: I had already created a new app pool specifically for this test site so I could shut it down when it started gobbling up all the CPU. its configured identically to the site that is working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended having to call Microsoft on this. They used **ProdDump** and **LogMan** to analyze what was happening. In less than 24hrs came back to me and said:

> "Thread 19 seems to be pretty badly bogging down the CPU. The top of
>   the stack indicates that AjaxMin is trying to do FindEntry on a
>   Dictionary object and this was triggered from AjaxControlToolKit,
>   specifically there appears to be something “CombineScripts” attribute
>   defined on either the Master page or in the design page of
>   OrderDetails.aspx. Basically this combines all the JS files and
>   minifies them.
>
> A quick test would be to disable the logic of CombineScript from
>   AjaxControlToolKit and see if that improves performance"

Google told me **CombineScripts** was an attribute of **ToolkitScriptManager** and since AJAX was always a suspect (for no real good reason, just a hunch) I jumped on it.

Sure enough, changing my reference to the **ToolkitScriptManager** to include **CombineScripts="false"** completely ***fixed the problem***!

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false" ScriptMode="Release" />
```

Related posts:
I'm not the only one: https://www.google.ca/#q=ToolkitScriptManager+combinescripts+problem

Two helpful posts:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1696523.aspx
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27558

Answer (score 0):

In the project project properties check for any reference to old version of Ajax control toolkit. If found any then remove the same and try again.

Comment: The only reference to the toolkit (and the ajaxmin & htmlagilitypack dependencies) were all version "Auto Update". I removed the references anyhow and re-added them back via Manage NuGet Packages. The same problem persists.
Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

I some times gave same error when I use nuget. I think conflict is your web.config assembly reference. Please compare your dll reference and web.config reference.

Comment: the only references in my web.config must be fine. thank you, though!
see below for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change .Net version for Application Pool to v4.0